# Property Editor Control for Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsview

Is there any Cocoa Widget which i can use to build a typical (well except in Interface Builder) GUI builder property inspector like RealBasic or Delphi has?

And is there a website where additional 3rd party Cocoa widgets are listed?

Comment: Care to include a screenshot of the sort of thing you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InspectorKit](http://www.degutis.org/blog/dev/open-source/2009/03/09/introducing-inspectorkit/) ([github](https://github.com/thmghtd/InspectorKit.framework)) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks thats already a start. Just thought that there is already something more advanced then the simple group classification. Something that can read the properties from XML description or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Core Data, you can option-drag a Core Data entity from Xcode (in your model) to an IB window and it will automatically create an inspector-type view. I'm not familiar with RealBasic so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mac programs traditionally don't include generic "property editor" UI's. There are probably many reasons for this, but perhaps the most salient is that a "property editor" (presumably one that automatically generates a UI from an object's properties) is rarely the best UI you could provide. Since user experience is highly prised on the Mac, most developers attempt to produce a more "custom" editor for the UI.

The OmniGroup apps have excellent "inspector" UIs—specific editors designed for asthetic appeal and user experience in a particular use case. The OmniAppKit.framework, part of the open-source offerings from the OmniGroup contains classes for implementing similar inspectors.