# PropertyGrid like control in Mac OS

Tags: macos, cocoa

is there any control in Mac OS like Microsoft PropertyGrid or I need to create it by hand from other simple controls?

[image]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing like this in AppKit.

When [someone asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081404/property-editor-control-for-cocoa), one of the responses mentions a framework called InspectorKit. The original link is broken, but here's a fork: https://github.com/thmghtd/InspectorKit.framework

Or you could create something yourself using components like [NSForm](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSForm_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

UIKit for Cocoa Touch does implement something like this in the [Settings app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11).